# Changing the value of a variable from within a method returns a 'random' number

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to make an inputhandler in Java. This is (a snippet of) the source code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Inputhandler{
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
public int InputInt;

public int GetInt(){    
    try{
        InputInt = br.read();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Input should be a number. Please try again\n");
            GetInt();
        }
    return InputInt;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the user input from line 10, and then set that input as the value of InputInt. However, when I execute the program and call the method like this:

```
Inputhandler in = new Inputhandler();
int a = in.GetInt("A question"); //I would input a number like 200
System.out.println(a);
```

It prints out, at least that's what it looks like it to me, a random number. Numbers like 51, 48, 55. What am I doing wrong here? Why isn't the number that I input assigned to InputInt?

I sorted it would have something to do with the pass-by-reference and pass-by-value, and I understand those principles. I (think I) fully understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481454/1910584) and can still not work it out.

Please help me out! 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `int` is actually [the byte value of a character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) you enter. Try

```
InputInt = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
```

instead.